# How to alter the class of a coredata entity to a subclass

Tags: core-data, polymorphism, entity, subclass, parent

I have a coredata model with a parent Entity type, and other Entities which are subclasses of the parent.

During runtime, I am first creating entities which are instances of the parent class.

Later on, I want to be able to specialize these entities so they become instances of the subclass. Basically I want to alter the class of entities. The change I want to make is :

entity.class = parent     ->     entity.class = child

Does coredata offer a way to do it cleanly, or do I have to do it manually, by removing the instance of the parent class and create an instance of the subclass, filling it with the attributes of the parent ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new object of the child entity and delete the previous object. The entity of a managed object cannot be changed after the object has been created.